# New impact panel feedback

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, profile-page

The impact panel seemed off/different to me lately, and that's because, well, **it is**.

---

There's a new Impact panel* and I feel it can use some adjustments.

**OLD            NEW**

[image][image]

There's all of this extra empty whitespace which looks very odd.

I think we should add back in the horizontal rule and provide a bit more spacing between the edits, flags and votes. (Like the way it was before)

I'm guessing that it's related to the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav).

<sub><sub>*This change was implemented across all sites</sub></sub>